# Migrating to Ipv6, how to impose the use of a specific scope?

Tags: java, android, tcp, scope, ipv6

I'm migrating my app from **Ipv4** (TCP) to **Ipv6** (TCP).

To contact the server, the client send a message to

> fe80::cc3a:61ff:fe5d:bed5

instead of

> 192.168.0.16

The rest of the code remains identical.

Curiously, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work. After a few hours of searching, I realized that a "scope" has been added to the end of the Ipv6 address (fe80::d6ae:5ff:fe43:c6e9%wlan0).

I noticed that it can be **%p2p0**, **%eth0** or **%wlan0**. Knowing that to work through the Wi-Fi, the scope has to be **%wlan0**, how could I impose the use of a specific scope?

I looked all the [Inet6Address](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address) methods without finding anything.

Comment: How are you getting this IP address to connect to in the first place?

Comment: I use a multicastSocket. I just realized that the problem isn't the scope but the use of a wrong interface. Is there a way to specify which interface to use?

Comment: I found MulticastSocket.setNetworkInterface() and MulticastSocket.setInterface().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MulticastSocket.setNetworkInterface()** is the solution.

```
MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket("5678");
NetworkInterface wifiInterface = null;
for (NetworkInterface networkInterface : Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()))
    if (networkInterface.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) {
        wifiInterface = networkInterface;
        break;
        }

multicastSocket.setNetworkInterface(wifiInterface);
```